# Efficient Creation of Class Variables from Wide Data Form in R DataFrame

Tags: r

I have a data frame - each individual has multiple visits. Drugs taken by each subject at each visit was documented in variables DRUG1-3 in a wide data form. The drugs can be categorized into a few classes (CLASS1- A,B,C; CLASS2- D,E,F; CLASS3- G,H,I). What is the best way to create variables ClASS1-3 that indicate whether a patient is taking any drugs in this class at each visit?

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
Visit <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3)
DRUG1 <- c("A","A","A","A","G","G","D","D","G")
DRUG2 <- c("A","G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G")
DRUG3 <- c("A","G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G")
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, DRUG1, DRUG2, DRUG3)
```

So the variable CLASS1 I want to create will be (1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0), CLASS2 will be (0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0), CLASS3 will be (0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1).

Comment: I presume the vectors are intended to be like `c("A","A","A","A","G","G","D","D","G")`?

Comment: The data you shared isn't valid R code so we can't copy/paste it. Those string values need to be in quotes. Like `DRUG1 <- c("A","A","A","A","G","G","D","D","G")` And then do you have some data structure which stores which class each drug is in? Or were you planning to hard-code that into the transformation code?

Comment: Your  most robust solution, imho, would be to transform your original data frame into long format , classify each drug and then summarise by patient and class. Then, if necessary, transform  back to wide format.

Comment: Yes! I corrected my question. Sorry about that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
lookup <- data.frame(drug = LETTERS[1:9],
                     class = paste0("CLASS", c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3)))

library(tidyverse) # using dplyr + tidyr
df |>
  pivot_longer(-c(ID:Visit), values_to = "drug") |>
  left_join(lookup) |>
  distinct(ID, Visit, class, dummy = 1) |>
  arrange(class) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = class, values_from = dummy, values_fill = 0)

# A tibble: 9 × 5
     ID Visit CLASS1 CLASS2 CLASS3
  <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     1     1      1      0      0
2     1     2      1      0      1
3     2     1      1      0      0
4     2     2      1      0      0
5     4     1      0      1      0
6     4     2      0      1      0
7     3     1      0      0      1
8     3     2      0      0      1
9     4     3      0      0      1
```

---

data

```
ID <- c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4)
Visit <- c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3)
DRUG1 <- c("A","A","A","A","G","G","D","D","G")
DRUG2 <- c("A","G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G")
DRUG3 <- c("A","G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G")
df <- data.frame(ID, Visit, DRUG1, DRUG2, DRUG3)
```

Comment: Perhaps you have one or more drugs not found in the lookup. You could add `filter(!is.na(class)) |>` after the `distinct` step so those are discarded, does that resolve?

Answer (score 2):

If the real data is organised like the toy data, grouping is imo not necessary:

```r
X = data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4),
               Visit = c(1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2,3),
               DRUG1 = c("A","A","A","A","G","G","D","D","G"),
               DRUG2 = c("A","G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G"),                 
               DRUG3 = c("A", "G","B","B","G","G","D","D","G"))

X[paste0("DRUG", 1:3)] = 
      +(mapply(`%in%`, X[paste0("DRUG", 1:3)], 
               list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E", "F"), c("G", "H", "I"))))
colnames(X[paste0("DRUG", 1:3)]) = paste0("Class", 1:3) # or sub() 

# results in 
  ID Visit Class1 Class2 Class3
1  1     1      1      0      0
2  1     2      1      0      1
3  2     1      1      0      0
4  2     2      1      0      0
5  3     1      0      0      1
6  3     2      0      0      1
7  4     1      0      1      0
8  4     2      0      1      0
9  4     3      0      0      1
```

If grouping is needed, we can easily wrap in `by()`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `` `%in%` `` in `mapply`.

```
> cl <- list(c("A", "B", "C"), c("D", "E", "F"), c("G", "H", "I"))
> cbind(df[1:2], +mapply(`%in%`, df[-(1:2)], cl)) |> 
+   setNames(c(names(df)[1:2], paste0('CLASS', seq_along(cl))))
  ID Visit CLASS1 CLASS2 CLASS3
1  1     1      1      0      0
2  1     2      1      0      1
3  2     1      1      0      0
4  2     2      1      0      0
5  3     1      0      0      1
6  3     2      0      0      1
7  4     1      0      1      0
8  4     2      0      1      0
9  4     3      0      0      1
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4), Visit = c(1, 
2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3), DRUG1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "G", "G", 
"D", "D", "G"), DRUG2 = c("A", "G", "B", "B", "G", "G", "D", 
"D", "G"), DRUG3 = c("A", "G", "B", "B", "G", "G", "D", "D", 
"G")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a helper function to evaluate drugs against classes in the current column

```
library(tidyverse)

col_equals <- function(d) {
+(paste(cur_column()) == d)
}
        
df %>%
mutate(across(matches("Drug"), ~
        { case_when(
.x %in% LETTERS[1:3] ~ col_equals("DRUG1"),
.x %in% LETTERS[4:5] ~ col_equals("DRUG2"),
.x %in% LETTERS[6:8] ~ col_equals("DRUG3"))
        },.names = "{str_replace(.col,'DRUG','CLASS')}"))


ID Visit DRUG1 DRUG2 DRUG3 CLASS1 CLASS2 CLASS3
1  1     1     A     A     A      1      0      0
2  1     2     A     G     G      1      0      1
3  2     1     A     B     B      1      0      0
4  2     2     A     B     B      1      0      0
5  3     1     G     G     G      0      0      1
6  3     2     G     G     G      0      0      1
7  4     1     D     D     D      0      1      0
8  4     2     D     D     D      0      1      0
9  4     3     G     G     G      0      0      1
```